# VsCode composer psr-4 autoload of external libraries does not perform code completion

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, composer-php, psr-4, intelephense

I have a self-made shared library that I am including in my Laravel project.

This is how the autoload part in my `composer.json` looks like:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "MyLib\\Base\\": "../../../.libraries/my-lib/packages/MyLib/Base/src/" <- NOTE THIS
        }
    },
```

I cannot autocomplete the names of the classes (or anything) when I am typing the code.

I wrote down `use MyLib\Base\Model\User;` in my code and then tried to use `User` model and it worked perfectly, but the code keep showing the error `Undefined type 'MyLib\Base\Model\User'.` and highlights it with red underline as an error.

Therefore I understand that the intelliphense is not able to recognize the shared library classes although they work fine!

Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution somewhere while I was trying a lot of things and this worked!

Just add this below json value in `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```
{
    "intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
        "../../../.libraries/my-lib/packages/MyLib/Base/src/"
    ]
}
```

Not only the error disappears, but also the code completion starts to work!